# Puppet agent certificate error after rebuilding openstack instance

Tags: linux, ssl, puppet, openstack

I have an open-stack instance vm , and puppet agent was working fine on it. By running the command `puppet agent -t`,  it was good. But for some reason i had to rebuild the instance by using the open-stack rebuild feature, now when i run the puppet agent command , it results in certificate error. What could be the problem? and a workaround for this? in principle there should be no error , because i have configured the puppet to auto-sign the certificates from my domain.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, then the problem is that your client expects a specific server certificate from the server.  When you rebuilt the server, you almost definitely created a new server certificate.

The easiest thing to do, if I recall correctly, is to erase `/var/lib/puppet/ssl` on the client.  That should erase any pre-existing certificates and force it to renegotiate new certificates.

Comment: the puppet server is the same , i don’t change anything on puppet master , i rebuild the client , so it should auto negotiate , isn’t it?